# rewrite rule in htaccess didnt work

Tags: .htaccess

im trying to beautify my urls, my urls are like that

```
   http://www.mysite.com/details.php?id=19&object=1
```

object=1 (videos) or object=0 (articles)

i want change this url to

```
    http://www.mysite.com/videos/19
```

of course i make videos because i mentioned that when object =1 means videos

and when object =0

i want this

```
    http://www.mysite.com/articles/19
```

I tried using this from some tutorials , but didnt work.nothing happen.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^videos/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ details.php?object=$1&id=$2
```

and also how do i do the if condition with `RewriteCond` to check if object is 1 or 0 , if 1 then print videos else articles.

any help would be much apreciated.

Comment: Do you have control over Apache config OR you are on a shared hosting?

Comment: @anubhava im on shared hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use [**`RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for your case here. Here is a sample how to use it:

1. Add following line to your `httpd.conf` file:

   ```
   RewriteMap objMap txt://path/to/objectMap.txt
   ```
2. Create a text file as `/path/to/objectMap.txt` like this:

   ```
   articles 0
   videos 1
   ```
3. Add these line in your .htaccess file under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /details.php?object=${objMap:$1}&id=$2 [L,QSA]
   ```

**Advantage:** With this setup in place, you can edit or recreate the file `/path/to/objectMap.txt` anytime you have a new object id mapping without any need to add new rules.

**UPDATE:** If you have no control over Apache config you will have to deal with multiple rewrite rules (one each of each object id mapping) like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\.php\?id=([^&]+)&object=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /videos/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\.php\?id=([^&]+)&object=0\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /articles/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/?$ /details.php?object=1&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$ /details.php?object=0&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I realized that and that's why provided an alternative solution as an update.

Comment: What URL did you use to test?

Comment: wait , im already having this `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` did i will replace it by yours ?

Comment: No that's fine let that option be there.

Comment: then i will add yours also ? with this `-MultiViews`

Comment: Yes definitely use `-MultiViews` otherwise it can create other problems.

Comment: used yours and nothing changed also. did this play a role if `details.php?id=7&object=1` or `details.php?object=1&id=7` , i mean if they are changed id and object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33662/discussion-between-anubhava-and-echo-me)

Comment: sorry i want ask you again because i feel you perfect in htaccess , just small question how to rewrite `..../file.php`  to `.../file/` and thank so much :)

Comment: Following should work: `RewriteRule ^\.(\.{3}/file)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R]` though I am amused at this strange redirect.